# Scheduled mapreduce job on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm developing a node.js application that basically **stores user event logs in a database and shows insights about user action**s.
For achieving this event logs must be analyzed by using a **Mapreduce** job which would run **once a day automatically** (every night).

I've found lots of tutorials about mapreduce on google cloud web site but I'm totally lost because there are several technologies and can't find a way to do it without using the command line and also there is no information about scheduling (**I want that the whole analysis process to be entirely automated**)

Please, could you provide me advice about what google technologies should I use or where I can find a good tutorial?

Thank you

Comment: Hello! So, a few quick questions so we can provide a (more) accurate answer. What is the size of the data you'll be processing? What format is the data in? Where is your Node application running - Google Cloud or elsewhere? Finally, do you want the results put anywhere specific or have any needs once the results are processed (like SQL query-ability, etc.)

Comment: Hi @James, basically the application is now deployed on amazon but I'm interested in migrate it to Google Cloud Platform. Currently I'm using a Mongodb database and its mapreduce feature but having to manage the database and disk space it is a pain.

Comment: @James: forgot to mention that results of the mapreduce process are sent to rabbitmq and finally saved in another mongodb database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to be looking at:

1. [Dataproc](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/) (run Hadoop/Spark jobs out of the box)
2. [Dataflow](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/) (develop 'pipelines' using the Dataflow/Beam programming model)